# AWS AppSync, Cognito & S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I would like to user AWS AppSync to upload pictures. Following what I have seen here is how I configured my appsync app.

Schema :

```
input PictureInput {
 ede_number: String!
 file: S3ObjectInput!
}

enum Visibility {
 public
 private
}

type S3Object {
 bucket: String!
 region: String!
 key: String!
}

input S3ObjectInput {
 bucket: String!
 region: String!
 localUri: String
 visibility: Visibility
 key: String
 mimeType: String
}

type Picture {
 picture_id: String!
 ede_number: String!
 file: S3Object
}

type Mutation {
 addPicture(picture: PictureInput!): Picture
}
```

Mapping resolver :

```
{
 "version": "2017-02-28",
 "operation": "PutItem",
 "key": {
    "picture_id":  { "S" : "${util.autoId()}"}
  },
 #set( $attribs = $util.dynamodb.toMapValues($ctx.args.picture) )
 #set( $attribs.author =   $util.dynamodb.toString($context.identity.username) )
 #set( $attribs.company = $util.dynamodb.toString($context.identity.claims.get("custom:company")) )
 #set( $file = $context.args.picture.file )
 #set( $attribs.file = $util.dynamodb.toS3Object($file.key, $file.bucket, $file.region) )
 #set( $attribs.created_at = $util.dynamodb.toString($util.time.nowISO8601()) )

 "attributeValues": $util.toJson($attribs)
}
```

In my react native app, here is how configure AWS AppSync client :

```
Amplify.configure({
 Auth: {
   mandatorySignIn: true,
   region: config.REGION,
   userPoolId: config.COGNITO_GROUP_ID,
   identityPoolId: config.COGNITO_IDENTITY_ID,
   userPoolWebClientId: config.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
 },
});

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
 url: config.APPSYNC_URL,
 region: config.REGION,
 auth: {
   type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS,
   jwtToken: async () =>
   (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
   credentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials(),
},
complexObjectsCredentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials(),
});
```

An finally this is how I make my mutation :

```
  let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    aspect: [4, 3],
  });

   const picture = {
    ede_number: farm.ede_number,
    file: {
      localUri: pickerResult.uri,
      bucket: config.BUCKET,
      key: uuid(),
      region: config.REGION,
    },
  };

  addPicture({
    variables: {
      picture,
    },
    optimisticResponse: {
      __typename: 'Mutation',
      addPicture: {
        __typename: 'Picture',
        ...picture,
        file: {
          __typename: 'S3Object',
          ...picture.file,
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

An entry is added in DynamoDb table but nothing in s3 bucket :(

When I try this

```
Auth.currentCredentials().then(cred => console.log(cred));
```

I have the following error message in the console :

```
"cannot get guest credentials when mandatory signin enabled"
```

I have added my cognito user in a group with arn role with S3 full access.

I have read this example : https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-amplify-graphql

and I don't see where is my mistake.

Thanks,

Comment: That comment roughly stems from your 'mandatorySignIn: true' flag. This requires some form of login token to be present when the client attempts to get credentials. I have two follow up questions:
1) Are you doing anything else with Amplify, talking to any other AWS service, without signing in first?
2) If not, did you create the user you're using with Cognito's AdminCreateUser API? If you sign in to their console and look at user pages, you can see user state. If you see FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD by that user, it can cause this.

Comment: User is not in FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD state. I am going deeper in aws code. I have the following issue : 
Auth.js:1172 {error: Error: Missing required key 'IdentityPoolId' in params
    at ParamValidator.fail (blob:http://192.1…}